# How can i create JavaScript test cases

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing

I am currently working on some test cases for my website. I've managed to test the back-end functionality using the simple-test framework.

I have some important javascript tools that requires some automatic testing. I know javascript is a client side language and it requires a browser, i am just wondering if its something i can do.

Notice the test must run from Linux CLI.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install node.js with [jasmine-node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) package to run your tests using cli:

Here's a brief intro to Jasmine:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/testing-your-javascript-with-jasmine/

And here's a tutorial on jasmine-node:

http://www.2ality.com/2011/10/jasmine.html

PS

In order to reference the code to be tested is useful to grasp how `module.export` works on Node.js ... here you'll find all the info you need to get started:  <s>http://jherdman.github.com/2010-04-05/understanding-nodejs-require.html</s> (broken link) http://coppieters.blogspot.be/2013/03/tutorial-explaining-module-export.html

Answer (score 2):

Jasmine is what I use for my Javascript testing. It can be found here : 
https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine (UPDATED -- 2015)

I also use JSCoverage to test my code coverage. It can be found here : http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/

Answer (score 1):

There are several unit testing frameworks out there written for javascript.

You could try something like:

> http://testcase.rubyforge.org/